# Detecting a feather touch

Tags: detection, vibration, pressure

New to the forum here, but I have a need to detect a feather touch. Is there any sensor that is recommended? This will be in a vibrating environment, so audio is probably out of the question. Is a force sensor sensitive enough?

I literally mean a feather touching the sensor. For example, I know force sensors measure resistance. I'd like to measure the resistance change. So, if condensation is on the sensor, and a fly lands on it, it will detect a change in resistance.

Comment: Could the feather remove charge?

Comment: Can you clarify - do you literally mean a feather is touching the sensor?  Or do you mean a feather-light touch of a finger?

Comment: Can anything besides a feather touch the sensor? Dust, condensation, etc.

Comment: If you vibrate a piezo disk, a feather touching it might damp the vibration and result in a change in properties (like current draw).

Comment: This site isn't a forum and product recommendations are off-topic AND you don't appear to have asked a valid EE question nor is there anywhere enough information in your question should it have been valid. Voting to close.

Comment: @Selvek I'm trying to measure anything from less than a gram to  up to 2 pounds or so. Anything else can touch the sensor and I don't care what it is, I just want to know that something is actually touching it.

Comment: An optical or ultrasonic sensor would detect anything large and solid regardless of weight.

Comment: A lever on a switch can be made very long and thus require little force, however the motion required at the end of the lever may be large.

Comment: The answer is obviously yes even if it involves engineering compromises, electronic microgram scales exist as commercial products. At school I had students design a capacitive scale that relied on nothing more than the change of capacitance of rising salt water on a plastic straw and it was able to measure less than 0.5g (it could resolve 1/2 a staple), the requirement for the class was 1g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether feather or finger, a physical presence is probably what you are trying to sense. How about a photoelectric setup. If the touchpad (non working, just a bull's eye for the finger) was recessed about a quarter inch, then the LED and sensor could look across the gap. The mere presence of anything would set it off.